A woman steals identity and marriages
I saw a part of an unknown movie in the nineties.
The plot is the following:
A woman (probably a lover of a rich man) travels with her man. They probably go from Europe to America by ship. One night she sees a girl, who jumps from the ship into the sea (commits suicide).
As the woman (rich man's lover) is bored by her life, she decides to take the girl's identity.
The girl was to marry a man in America, but she knew him only by letters. So the woman decides to present herself as the girl and marry her man.
In the beginning everything goes okay, her future husband does not recognise her or realise that he was fooled. However, at the wedding night the woman has to sleep with the jeweller to "pay" for her wedding ring.
I don't remember the year, when I saw the movie on the tv. It was between 1991 to 99. It was in English (US) language.
The future husband was "latino" type guy. He was living with his parents in poor to middle class area. I remember that all the people in the village were surprised, when she received the engagement ring, because it was so expensive.
I also remember that the husband asked her (at the wedding night, just before the jeweller came into the room): "Would you do anything to make me happy?"

Do you know language /country/release year or decade or how does this character looked like

You're looking for Naked Tango from 1991 with Vincent D'Onofrio.

Returning by ship to Buenos Aires, a young woman escapes her elderly husband by swapping places with a woman committing suicide. She believes her new life will be that of an arranged marriage but finds it is in fact a ruse to cause her to work in a brothel.

You can see the scene where she has to pleasure the jeweller to "make her husband happy" here (Warning: Scene Rated R for violence and sexual themes), and here's the trailer:



